# What are possible causes of my python script ending prematurely?

Tags: python, sockets, recursion, tcp, client

I have a python script that communicates with other software through TCP/IP protocol. It receives data in XML format from the software. This worked fine. However, since it is part of a larger project I packed the modules and installed them into my project environment.

In some mysterious way, my script in the project environment is ending prematurely.

The script ends somewhere in the function below because when I print the lines from the message it ends somewhere halfway.

```
    def to_line(self, message: RecievedMessage):
        sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
        if len(self.data[0]) > 0:
            size = ord(self.data[0])
            line = "".join(self.data[4:size + 4]).strip()
            # print(line)
            message.recieved_lines.append(RecievedMessage.RecievedLine(size=size, data=line))
            del self.data[0: size + 4]
            self.to_line(message)
        else:
            return message
```

I tried to find the obvious errors by breaking the code, such as setting the recursion limit to low. But the common errors are caught.

EDIT: to_line() method uses an if statement to check the recursive base case, instead of the previous try except block.

SOLUTION:

'''

```
def to_line(self) -> None:
    while len(self.data[0]) > 0:
        size = ord(self.data[0])
        line = "".join(self.data[4:size + 4]).strip()
        self.message.recieved_lines.append(RecievedMessage.RecievedLine(size=size, data=line))
        del self.data[0: size + 4]
```

'''

Comment: Why are you importing in a function and why is there no return in the try block?

Comment: its imported in the function because I don't use sys elsewhere. There is no return in the try block because it should run until the entire message is formatted into xml.

Comment: It does neither print an error message nor returns `message`?

Comment: My bet is that a recursion limit of 1.000.000 isn't something Python can handle, seeing the default is 1.000.

Comment: It returns the message as expected. It needs a higher recursion limit because the file has over 1000 lines. The problem arises when I packed the modules and distribute them into my project environment. In that case, the module doesn't behave as expected and the scripts stops running halfway the translation of the received message.

Comment: Are you sure you need recursion for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely ran out of memory. In this case, the python interpreter might just exit without an error message or with just the usual message from your operating system. (something like "[...] terminated unexpectedly")

It is generally a bad idea to increase the recursion limit. If you need a higher recursion limit, there is generally just a problem with your code. As a rule of thumb: If you can write something as a loop in Python, you should write it as a loop. Else you will keep all unneeded local variables in memory and quickly run out of it.

In your case, it is simple: Just replace `if` with `while` and remove the recursive call.

```
def to_line(self, message: RecievedMessage) -> RecievedMessage:
    while len(self.data[0]) > 0:
        size = ord(self.data[0])
        line = "".join(self.data[4:size + 4]).strip()
        # print(line)
        message.recieved_lines.append(RecievedMessage.RecievedLine(size=size, data=line))
        del self.data[0: size + 4]
    return message
```

There a further things that are strange in your code: What is `self.data` containing? If you call `ord`, it seemingly is a string (or a list of characters), but then `len(self.data[0])` makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks this seemed to be the problem.

Comment: At the end of the loop, an empty list with an empty string is left over [""], that is why I check if len(self.data[0]) > 0.  Also, your solution works besides the return statement. The return statement should be left out, and the input has also became obsolete.